# Laravel Backpack - How to apply the Search function on filters

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using the Backback package and I struggle to create a text filter updating the table like the search input do.

[image]

I would like to have the search function applied to a single column without reloading the page.

Thank you for your time,